# How can I get my CSS animation to work without affecting the surrounding elements?

Tags: html, css

How can I get my animation to work without affecting the surrounding elements? In this case, without moving the text around it.

[The JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0kf7e8pL/)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="icon" href="" />
        <style type="text/css">
            html, body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                color: #131313;
                font-family: sans-serif;
            }

            #content {
                margin: 2em;
            }

            #test {
                margin: 2em 2em 0.25em 2em;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: row;
                align-items: center;
            }

            #test > div:last-child {
                margin: 0 2em;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                align-items: flex-start;
            }

            .highlight {
                color: #00FFFF;
            }

            .throb {
                animation-name: throb;
                animation-duration: 1500ms;
                animation-iteration-count: infinite;
                animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            }

            @keyframes throb {
                0% {
                    width: 100px;
                    transform: rotate(0deg);
                }
                12.5% {
                    transform: rotate(45deg);
                }
                25% {
                    transform: rotate(90deg);
                }
                37.5% {
                    transform: rotate(135deg);
                }
                50% {
                    width: 105px;
                    transform: rotate(180deg);
                }
                62.5% {
                    transform: rotate(225deg);
                }
                75% {
                    transform: rotate(270deg);
                }
                87.5% {
                    transform: rotate(315deg);
                }
                100% {
                    width: 100px;
                    transform: rotate(360deg);
                }
            }
        </style>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="test">
            <img src="wheel.png" width="100px" />
            <div>
                <div>the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
                <div>THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            const RECORD = document.querySelector('img');
            RECORD.classList.add('throb');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are increasing the `width` of the image by 5px in keyframes which causes the shift. You'll need to remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shift occurs due to change in width during animation. You could achieve a similar effect using `transform:scale` and removing `width` property

```js
const RECORD = document.querySelector("img");
RECORD.classList.add("throb");
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #131313;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#content {
  margin: 2em;
}

#test {
  margin: 2em 2em 0.25em 2em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

#test>div:last-child {
  margin: 0 2em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.highlight {
  color: #00ffff;
}

.throb {
  animation-name: throb;
  animation-duration: 1500ms;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
}

@keyframes throb {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);
  }
  12.5% {
    transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.01);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(90deg) scale(1.02);
  }
  37.5% {
    transform: rotate(135deg) scale(1.03);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg) scale(1.04);
  }
  62.5% {
    transform: rotate(225deg) scale(1.03);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(270deg) scale(1.02);
  }
  87.5% {
    transform: rotate(315deg) scale(1.01);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <img src="data:image/png;base64,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"
    width="100px" />
  <div>
    <div>the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
    <div>THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's weird ... I tried `scale()`, but it never worked; it just stayed the same size, but here it is working.

Comment: That's weird. Do you have the fiddle link? Also, you need to add the `scale` property with the existing `rotate` property as shown in the solution. Adding it as a separate `transform` property won't work because css will read only one `transform` property

Comment: Ah, that's it. Until your comment I didn't know I could combine the transforms, and I had the scale and rotate on different lines. Thank you for clearing that up for me! I like the `scale()` much better than changing the width.

Answer (score 1):

it's the width property in your animation that is affecting the layout.
to solve this keeping your animation key frames as is. wrap the image in a div give it the same width and height as the image and set `position: absolute` on the image.

the absolute positioning detaches the element from the layout

Comment: Sweet ... that worked! [finished product](https://jsfiddle.net/g7epc9o2/). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your animation changes the image width, causing the text to shift. I fixed this by wrapping the image in a div and making the div as big as the image gets in the animation (105px). I then centered the image in the div.

```
<style>
...

  .image-container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 105px;
    height: 105px;
  }

...
}

...

<div class='image-container'>
  <img src="..." width="100px" />
</div>

...
```

Hope this helps!